# What has changed in the AuthorizeAttribute in ASP.NET Web API 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I have upgraded a project and set of unit tests from ASP.NET Web API to ASP.NET Web API 2.

We are using a custom `DelegatingHandler` for a custom authentication mechanism.

It sets the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` and `HttpContext.Current.User` to the appropriate `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal`.

- When hosted in IIS, i.e. running normally, both are set.
- In the unit tests, only the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is set because `HttpContext.Current` is `null`.

Since upgrading to ASP.NET Web API 2, with no other code changes, the web hosted version works fine but the unit tests fail. They worked before the upgrade.

**Does ASP.NET Web API 2 now *require* the principal to be set in the `HttpContext`?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In web API 2, you will need to call `GetRequestContext()` on the request object and set the `Principal` property to your claims principal.

Go to http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1294 and find "davidmatson wrote Sep 13 at 10:18 PM".

Comment: THANK YOU!  This took WAY, WAY too long too find.  Everyone +1 this answer and this question!